# execute php statement if button is clicked

Tags: php, if-statement, button, click, execute

I want to execute a PHP statement if my html button is clicked, so I created a button like this :

```html
<form method="post"> <input name="logout" type="submit" id="submit" value="logout" /> </form>
```

And then i have my php if statement code :

```html
if (isset($_POST['logout']))
 {
  echo "Hello world!";
 }
```

doesn't really work and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you wrap the button in a `<form>` with `method="POST"` and an action pointing to your PHP page?

Comment: you need to use the `<form>` tag with method `POST`

Comment: Could you post all form code(form action, etc)?

Comment: Yes i do this just now... <form method="post"> <input name="logout" type="submit" id="submit" value="logout" /> </form> but this don't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have written your PHP code on the same page.

When you press submit button, it requires form that. Please make sure that you have written form tag and action is the same url or the url of the page where you wrote PHP code.

And as you have checked for post, your method of form must be post.

If all things are correct then please specify your full code here

Comment: Thank you for your response, i tried this : <form method="post">         
<input name="logout" type="submit" id="submit" value="logout" />                      </form> but this don't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer assumed you wanted to stay on the same page. If that is not the case, Ajax is not the only solution.

PHP is finished executing as soon as the page loads. Then JavaScript will execute. Every time, always.

You can do what you are trying to achieve through an AJAX request, which will effectively go behind the scenes to load a new page (and therefore load a new script).

jQuery makes using Ajax fairly simple.

```
url = 'path/to/your/script.php';
$.get(url, function(d){
    alert("User " + d.name' + " has been logged out.");
});
```

In this case, the first argument is the url that javascript will go to. The second argument is a function to do with the returned data (d). This example shows `script.php` returning the name of the user being logged out, which is accessed through `d.name`. This example lets the user know the button worked by popping up an alert.